# My film camera’s exposures count went back to 1?

Tags: film, 35mm, fujifilm, point-and-shoot, konica

I made a beginner’s mistake I opened the film chamber several times, that might be a thing.
I also tried using the remote control on my Konica z-up 80 and I’m not even sure if it took any shots
I suddenly found the exposure’s counter set to 1 even though I took around 23-27 exposures I can’t remember exactly:(
In conclusion:
Did I screw up everything completely?
Should I give up and get another roll?
Should I continue using mine?
Do I just develop this one already?

Comment: "opened the film chamber" - then the exposure count is the least of your worries unless you did this in a totally dark room or a film changing bag.

Comment: Please take a look at this question and the answers there: [Can I still use film after the film door accidentally opened?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/126232) NEVER open the door of your film camera when you've got a roll of film inside. I still just can't fathom why people do this. Film is extremely light-sensitive. Sorry to sound a bit harsh, but there just isn't any ambiguity around this. It's a physical/chemical process. It's like emptying a can of paint on a table and somehow hoping that the table doesn't change colour.

Comment: Thank you so much I’ll definitely be more careful next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When the rear of the camera is opened, any film that gets exposed to light is ruined. Any film that is concealed from light – and I mean really concealed – is saved.
2. When you use the remote, listen for the sound of the shutter and film advance mechanism. Check the frame counter too – if it goes up by one, then a frame has been exposed. If it hasn't gone up, then check/change the battery in the remote.
3. Most automatic cameras will reset the frame counter when the rear of the camera is opened. When you close the rear again, the camera usually assumes you've put a fresh roll of film inside, and it should advance the film by a small amount to ensure that unexposed film is sitting behind the lens.

I would say... continue using this roll until the end is reached, but maybe best not to use it for anything critical. Get it developed (or do it yourself). Take note of how everything turns out, and just use it as a learning experience if nothing else. If a lab is developing it, it's probably worth mentioning to them in advance what you've done.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I’ll send it to a lab asap and I’ve already told them so, I’ll see what happens, and I’ll count this one as an experiment!